# add the values in a list and display total price react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to make a bill and want to add items to the bill when i add a items multiple time  i want to increment the total price also i want it to be displayed as total amount when i decrease the amount i want to decrement the pice from both

pls have a look at the codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/still-https-ztn52x?file=/src/dashbord.jsx

```
 function bill({ billItems }) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="foo">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>item</th> <th>price</th> <th>qty</th> <th>total_price</th>
              </tr>
              {trayItems &&
                trayItems.map((ele, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{ele.item}</td>
                      <td>{ele.price}</td>

                      <td>{ele.quantity}</td>
                      <th>0</th>
                      <td>
                        <button onClick={() => incre(ele.user_id)}>+</button>
                        <button onClick={() => decre(ele.user_id)}>-</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {item &&
          item
            .filter((person) => person.status === 0)
            .map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", border: "1px solid black" }}
                  key={index}
                  className="newmo-card"
                  onClick={() => handleCheckClick(ele)}
                >
                  {`${ele.item}`}
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <span> {`${ele.total_price}`}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
      <bill billItems={billItems} />
      <h3> total amount 0</h3>
    </>
```

also i want to remove the item from list when the quantity is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter `trayItems` when you map them in `decre` function.  This will remove the items that have a quantity less than or equal to 1.

You need to calculate the total. There are 2 ways to go about it. Either create a new state that stores a calculated total or calculate it on the fly while managing/manipulating the `trayItems's` `totalPrice`. I have created a new state rather than making it more complex. You will need to re-render when the total changes so do that calculation inside a `useEffect` hook for re-render when the total changes.

Here is my solution:

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const item = [
  {
    user_id: 1,
    item: "biriani",
    price: "50",
    selling_price: "60",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:12:58.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T14:05:45.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    item: "alfarm",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 4,
    item: "burger",
    price: "80",
    selling_price: "80",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:21:13.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-14T04:46:36.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "100",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 8,
    item: "sandwich",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-14T04:46:37.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 9,
    item: "pizza",
    price: "200",
    selling_price: "220",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "240",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 10,
    item: "chicken sadwich",
    price: "200",
    selling_price: "220",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "250",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 11,
    item: "sharja shake",
    price: "60",
    selling_price: "70",
    created_at: "2022-09-09T06:58:45.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T14:05:53.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },

  {
    user_id: 1,
    item: "biriani",
    price: "50",
    selling_price: "60",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:12:58.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T06:17:20.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 1,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    item: "alfarm",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [trayItems, settrayItems] = useState([]);
  console.log(trayItems);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    let newTotal = 0;
    trayItems.forEach((stat) => {
      newTotal += stat.price * stat.quantity;
    });
    setTotal(newTotal);
  }, [trayItems]);

  const handleCheckClick = (ele) => {
    const dupe = trayItems.find((obj) => obj.user_id === ele.user_id);
    settrayItems(
      dupe
        ? trayItems
        : [...trayItems, { ...ele, quantity: (ele.quantity = 1) }]
    );
  };

  const incre = (idd) => {
    settrayItems(
      trayItems.map((stat) =>
        stat.user_id === idd ? { ...stat, quantity: stat.quantity + 1 } : stat
      )
    );
  };
  const deleteFromTray = (currentTray, id) => {
    return currentTray.filter((item) => item.user_id !== id);
  };

  const decre = (idd) => {
    trayItems.every((stat, index) => {
      if (stat.user_id === idd) {
        stat.quantity > 1
          ? settrayItems([
              ...trayItems.slice(0, index),
              {
                ...stat,
                quantity: stat.quantity - 1
              },
              ...trayItems.slice(index + 1, trayItems.length)
            ])
          : settrayItems([
              ...trayItems.slice(0, index),
              ...trayItems.slice(index + 1, trayItems.length)
            ]);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });

    console.log("trashcoder", trayItems);
  };

  function Tray({ trayItems }) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="foo">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>item</th> <th>price</th> <th>qty</th> <th>total_price</th>
              </tr>
              {trayItems &&
                trayItems.map((ele, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{ele.item}</td>
                      <td>{ele.price}</td>

                      <td>{ele.quantity}</td>
                      <th>{ele.price * ele.quantity}</th>
                      <td>
                        <button onClick={() => incre(ele.user_id)}>+</button>
                        <button onClick={() => decre(ele.user_id)}>-</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {item &&
          item
            .filter((person) => person.status === 0)
            .map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", border: "1px solid black" }}
                  key={index}
                  className="newmo-card"
                  onClick={() => handleCheckClick(ele)}
                >
                  {`${ele.item}`}
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <span> {`${ele.total_price}`}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
      <Tray trayItems={trayItems} />
      <h3> total amount {total}</h3>
    </>
  );
}
```

CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-brook-sj207w?file=/src/dashbord.jsx:0-5500

Answer (score 2):

First, in the map of tray items you can multiple the quantity and price for the total

```
change this
<th>0</th>

to this 
<th>{ele.quantity * ele.price}</th>
```

As for displaying the total amount for each item, you need to create a function that will add all the items price * quantity. Here's sample function and implementation for your reference.

```
  const handleTotal = () => {
      // reduce will add all of your price and set a default value in case the items is empty
      return trayItems.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => Number(acc) + (curr.quantity * Number(curr.price)),0
      );
    }

then you need to change this 

<h3> total amount 0</h3>

to this

<h3>{`total amount ${handleTotal()}}</h3>
```

For removing the item if the quantity is 0, first, you need to modify your decrement function so that it will allow to make the quantity 0

```
const decre = (idd) => {
    settrayItems(
      trayItems.map((stat) =>
        stat.user_id === idd
          ? {
              ...stat,
              quantity:
                stat.quantity !== 1 ? stat.quantity - 1 : (stat.quantity = 0)
            }
          : stat
      )
    );
  };
```

Then add a checker that will show if the quantity is greater than 0

```
{trayItems &&
                trayItems.map((ele, index) => {
                  if (ele.quantity > 0) {
                    return (
                      <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{ele.item}</td>
                        <td>{ele.price}</td>

                        <td>{ele.quantity}</td>
                        <th>0</th>
                        <td>
                          <button onClick={() => incre(ele.user_id)}>+</button>
                          <button onClick={() => decre(ele.user_id)}>-</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  }
                })}
```

To re add the item again in the tray you need to modify the handleCheckClick so that if the trayItem.quantity is equal to 0 it will add 1 to it.

```
const handleCheckClick = (ele) => {
    const dupe = trayItems.find((obj) => obj.user_id === ele.user_id);
    settrayItems(
      dupe
        ? trayItems.map((item) => {
            if (item.quantity > 0) return item;
            return {
              ...item,
              quantity: item.quantity + 1
            };
          })
        : [...trayItems, { ...ele, quantity: (ele.quantity = 1) }]
    );
  };
```

Comment: for some reason i am getinng total amount [object Object]

Comment: You need to convert the price as Number because It's a string

Comment: can u make edit in the answer what i must be changing

Comment: I edit it now, I also remove the if statement because there's a default value in reduce method which is 0

Comment: oke thanx but can u help me fix the last part of my question   i want to remove the item from list when the quantity is 0

Comment: I edit the answer for your reference. Hope this solve your problem thanks!

Comment: i tryed your code the issue is that when 0 ethe item gets removed but then if i try to add that iteam again it does not work

Comment: Hello, I edit the answer to this question if this works please let me know thanks!

Comment: when i add items and then make every items quntity to 0 and then i try to add a single item every previosily added items count is set to 1 pls help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, clean your data. Always make sure your data is in a good state before using it.

I added a filtering in your decre function. This will filter out items with no quantity (also, I'm doing the mapping on the "previous state").

A new state is added (total). The value is updated every time the trayItems state is updated (useEffect).

However, I would suggest you to use a [reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead.

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-chatelet-d9oe8f?file=/src/dashbord.jsx

Comment: agreed, The state design needs to be addressed. My suggestion is that separate the `bill` related properties like `quantity` and `total_price` into a separate state maybe called `cart` or even `bill`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and also solved it can you check it if you want exactly like this or anything different:

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const item = [
  {
    user_id: 1,
    item: "biriani",
    price: "50",
    selling_price: "60",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:12:58.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T14:05:45.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    item: "alfarm",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 4,
    item: "burger",
    price: "80",
    selling_price: "80",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:21:13.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-14T04:46:36.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "100",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 8,
    item: "sandwich",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-14T04:46:37.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 9,
    item: "pizza",
    price: "200",
    selling_price: "220",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "240",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 10,
    item: "chicken sadwich",
    price: "200",
    selling_price: "220",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "250",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 11,
    item: "sharja shake",
    price: "60",
    selling_price: "70",
    created_at: "2022-09-09T06:58:45.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T14:05:53.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },

  {
    user_id: 1,
    item: "biriani",
    price: "50",
    selling_price: "60",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:12:58.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T06:17:20.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 1,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    item: "alfarm",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [trayItems, settrayItems] = useState([]);
  const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);
  console.log(trayItems);

  const handleCheckClick = (ele) => {
    const dupe = trayItems.find((obj) => obj.user_id === ele.user_id);
    settrayItems(
      dupe
        ? trayItems
        : [...trayItems, { ...ele, quantity: (ele.quantity = 1) }]
    );
  };

  const incre = (idd) => {
    settrayItems(
      trayItems.map((stat) =>
        stat.user_id === idd ? { ...stat, quantity: stat.quantity + 1 } : stat
      )
    );
  
  };

  const decre = (idd) => {
    settrayItems(
      trayItems.map((stat) =>
        stat.user_id === idd
          ? {
              ...stat,
              quantity:
                stat.quantity !== 1 ? stat.quantity - 1 : (stat.quantity = 1)
            }
          : stat
      )
    );
    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let tt = trayItems.reduce((accumulator, object) => {
      return accumulator + (Number(object.price) * object.quantity);
    }, 0);
    setTotalAmount(tt);
  }, [trayItems]); // just calculate the amount based on item and quantity

  function Tray({ trayItems }) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="foo">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>item</th> <th>price</th> <th>qty</th> <th>total_price</th>
              </tr>
              {trayItems &&
                trayItems.map((ele, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{ele.item}</td>
                      <td>{ele.price}</td>

                      <td>{ele.quantity}</td>
                      <th>0</th>
                      <td>
                        <button onClick={() => incre(ele.user_id)}>+</button>
                        <button onClick={() => decre(ele.user_id)}>-</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {item &&
          item
            .filter((person) => person.status === 0)
            .map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", border: "1px solid black" }}
                  key={index}
                  className="newmo-card"
                  onClick={() => handleCheckClick(ele)}
                >
                  {`${ele.item}`}
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <span> {`${ele.total_price}`}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
      <Tray trayItems={trayItems} />
      <h3> total amount {totalAmount}</h3>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: can u make a codesanbox so i can test the code

Comment: here is the link you can check: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-field-jpdp7v?file=/src/App.js)